# Android Native Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextField Selected By Default

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

In Android Native Jetpack Compose, using the material `androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField` composable, is there some way to cause the default value I put in the field to be selected as soon as the field gets focus? Right now the cursor in the field is at the end of the data, so that if the user wants to change the default, they have to delete the old data, and then replace it. If the data in the field was already selected when the screen is rendered, the user could just type the new value to replace the entire default contents of the field.

I’m not seeing any parameters of the object that seem to do what I’d need. I’m wondering if there is some other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the cursor value when you set the Initial value to the `TextField`

**Output:**
[image: preview]

This is how you can make your text selected.

```
@Composable
fun OutLineTextFieldAutoSelected() {

    val text = "Default Value"

    val searchTextFieldValue =
        remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text)) }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = searchTextFieldValue.value,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onFocusChanged { state ->
                    if (state.hasFocus) {
                        searchTextFieldValue.value = searchTextFieldValue.value.copy(
                            selection = TextRange(
                                0,
                                searchTextFieldValue.value.text.length
                            )
                        )
                    }
                },
            onValueChange = {
                searchTextFieldValue.value = it
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
            singleLine = true,
            colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                cursorColor = Color.Black,
                focusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
            ),
            placeholder = {
                Text(
                    text = "Enter your text",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 14.sp,
                        color = Color.LightGray
                    )
                )
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                autoCorrect = true,
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @chirag, this kind of works. I have three fields I am doing this with. The first one works fine, the text is highlighted when I click on the field. The second field does not highlight, even though I verified that it has focus. If I click into another field and then go back to the second one, it works from then on. Not sure why all but the first field need me to click in, click away, and then click back into the field.

Comment: Never mind - it seems to be working now, not sure why it was wrong before.